# spinner selected item

Tags: android, spinner, selected

I've been reading stuff about this for hours and still haven't figured out how to do it.

I managed to populate a spinner from a cursor reading the database and now I'm trying to get the selected item on the spinner to help fill a listview.

Here's my code:

```
Cursor cursorpf = DatabaseHelper.getPFunc();
    startManagingCursor(cursorpf);

    Spinner spinnerpf = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    String[] frompf = new String[] { "Designacao" };
    int[] topf = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter scaPFunc = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursorpf, frompf, topf);
    scaPFunc
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerpf.setAdapter(scaPFunc);
    spinnerpf.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    final String stringpf = MyOnItemSelectedListener.getSelected();
            long id = spinnerpf.getSelectedItemId();
    String stringpf = String.valueOf(id);
    DatabaseHelper.setPF(stringpf);
```

MyOnItemSelectedListener class:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private static String selected = "";

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {        

    selected = String.valueOf(id);
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Escolha: " + selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}
```

}

The toast on this class returns the cursor position. Now, I know I must compare it against the database to get the value I want, but I just can't do it. Would you please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:
Guys, would you help me out?
I managed to get the selected item by implementing the code above, but it happens that the listview is only filled when the app starts. When I select something on the spinner, nothing happens. :|**

Comment: In case no one has looked at this before I get home, I'll help ya out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve selected item from database, just pass the fourth argument of `onItemSelected` (`id`) to you SQL query. It's the row id of the record, aka `_ID`.

Comment: I'm already passing it to the query. The problem is I'm passing the value and not the cursor position. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. `onItemSelected` has cursor position (3d arg) and row id (4th one). What else do you need?

Comment: I think i understand what I have to do. But now, for some reason, I manage to call the get method from the MyOnItemSelectedListener class but the string doesn't receive anything. Think I'll give it a rest for today...

Comment: Ok guys... a few days ago I managed to get the value I wanted by replacing the code with "selected = String.valueOf(id);".

The issue now is that I'm trying to return the value to the other classe but I can't get it to work, as this...

    final String stringpf = MyOnItemSelectedListener.getSelected();

... doesn't seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: I don't understand your approach. Using getters in listeners is probably wrong.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I got it:

    long id = spinnerpf.getSelectedItemId();
    String stringpf = String.valueOf(id);